# Why do .Net5 projects have a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic?

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net-5

The following code can be compiled and run, without having an explicit reference to a Microsoft.VisualBasic dll or package:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

Interaction.Beep(); // from Microsoft.VisualBasic

System.Console.WriteLine("Done");
```

Here the corresponding project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it? It's ".NET 5", not ".NET 5 C# Edition". You don't reference individual runtime DLLs in .NET Core / .NET 5: everything is just included by default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look under *Dependencies* > *Frameworks* in the Solution Explorer and you'll see *Microsoft.NETCore.App* listed. Expand that node and you'll see all the assemblies included in that framework, which includes `Microsoft.CSharp`, `Microsoft.VisualBasic` and `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core`. That means that VB projects have a reference to `Microsoft.CSharp` as well.

Comment: Is this view also available in VS Code?

Comment: I don't use VS Code so I'm not sure but I doubt it. You may be able to execute a command to list dependencies but that's just a guess.